# JavaScript Collision - Arguing DOM style.properties

Tags: javascript, html, properties, collision

I keep getting an Error in JavaScript program, when arguing the collision of two DOM elements based on their style.properties. My alert function is never triggered based on the following if-statement:

```
<script>
var sprite = null;
var enemy = null;

   sprite = document.getElementById('hero');
   enemy = document.getElementById('enemy');

if ( (sprite.style.top==enemy.style.top) 
  && (sprite.style.left==enemy.style.left) )
    {alert("intersects");}

</script>
```

- Thanks for any help with this if-statement to trigger the alert()

Comment: That's a typo, change `enemy.sprite.left` to `enemy.style.left`

Comment: adeneo > would the style.properties be enough to recognize the intersection?  Do I need to add + 'px'? Thanks for your help.

Comment: The styles are already returned as strings with `px`, so if both strings match, the elements have to same styles etc.